# android service works in version 2.2 but fails in higher versions

Tags: android

Greetings guys and i apologies in advance if i seem to stumble here but i a pretty new to android development

the scenario is
i have build a simple gps tracking app. essentially the user can click a panic button or a checking button or sms to active a service.
everything works fine in version 2.2 which is what i targeted in my build but when tested on a htc running 2.3.4 the app crashes as soon as any function calls the service.

in short the service checks the database for the users pin in the database here is Pinbox_db
it then gets the gps position and once received issues a http call to the web service to post the long and lat of the device

again i am sorry if this seems trivial to you more experienced developers but i am in very new grounds and appreciate your feedback

here is my service code

```
  package com.artgraven.misafety;


  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;   
  import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

  import android.app.Service;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.location.Location;
  import android.location.LocationManager;
  import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.IBinder;
  import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;


  public class Bg_process extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1500;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 20f;
public static String b_c_long;
public static String b_c_lat;
public static String alert_pin = "", alert_type ="undefined", alert_device ="android", alert_imei="32154",alert_sim_serial="0796768445";
private Pinbox_db entry = new Pinbox_db(Bg_process.this);
public static String recordSet = "PIN";

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
    Location mLastLocation;
    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);

    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        String message = String.format(
                "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());

        Toast.makeText(Bg_process.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        b_c_long = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        b_c_lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

        postData();

    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);            
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
} 
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)

};


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
     super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);       
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
   // alert_type = intent.getStringExtra("code");
    alert_type = extras.getString("code");


    return START_STICKY;


}
@Override
public void onCreate()
{   
    // get pin
    entry.open();
    recordSet = entry.getPin();
    entry.close();
    alert_pin = recordSet;

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("MOBILE"))
            alert_device = "android:  cellnetwork/3G";
        else if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getTypeName().equals("WIFI"))
            alert_device = "android: wifi";
        else 
            alert_device ="android: na"; 

        alert_sim_serial = tm.getLine1Number();
        alert_imei = tm.getDeviceId();



    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);


    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
} 
public static void postData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.website.co.za/api/activity_log.php");
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_long", b_c_long));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_lat", b_c_lat));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_pin", alert_pin));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_type", alert_type));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_device", alert_device));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_imei", alert_imei));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_sim_serial", alert_sim_serial));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = mLocationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            Toast.makeText(Bg_process.this, " " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            b_c_long = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            b_c_lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

            postData();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Bg_process.this, "current location unavailable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}

}
```

thank you very much for any feedback in advance

here is the session logCat

```
 11-19 21:15:56.030: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(639): LocationListener gps
 11-19 21:15:56.070: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(639): LocationListener network
 11-19 21:15:56.330: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(639): onCreate
 11-19 21:15:56.330: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(639): initializeLocationManager
 11-19 21:15:56.430: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(639): onStartCommand
 11-19 21:15:56.520: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(639): onLocationChanged: Location[mProvider=gps,mTime=1353268800000,mLatitude=37.422005,mLongitude=-122.084095,mHasAltitude=true,mAltitude=0.0,mHasSpeed=false,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0,mHasAccuracy=false,mAccuracy=0.0,mExtras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=4]]
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at com.artgraven.misafety.Bg_process.postData(Bg_process.java:188)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at com.artgraven.misafety.Bg_process$LocationListener.onLocationChanged(Bg_process.java:62)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:234)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:167)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:183)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 11-19 21:15:56.810: E/AndroidRuntime(639):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-19 21:16:05.839: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(653): LocationListener network
 11-19 21:16:05.909: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(653): onCreate
 11-19 21:16:05.909: E/BOOMBOOMTESTGPS(653): initializeLocationManager
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.artgraven.misafety.Bg_process: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2263)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at com.artgraven.misafety.Bg_process.postData(Bg_process.java:188)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at com.artgraven.misafety.Bg_process.initializeLocationManager(Bg_process.java:211)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at com.artgraven.misafety.Bg_process.onCreate(Bg_process.java:134)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2253)
 11-19 21:16:06.019: E/AndroidRuntime(653):     ... 10 more
```

this updated logcat is from a higher api version (15)
after implementing the suggested answer the problem was solved on emulators but when testing on devices the following error occurs

```
12-08 18:12:47.360: W/dalvikvm(21432): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401b1760)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.artgraven.specialopstech.Bg_process: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2049)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1059)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at com.artgraven.specialopstech.Bg_process.postData(Bg_process.java:192)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at com.artgraven.specialopstech.Bg_process.initializeLocationManager(Bg_process.java:215)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at com.artgraven.specialopstech.Bg_process.onCreate(Bg_process.java:138)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2039)
12-08 18:12:47.360: E/AndroidRuntime(21432):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: what errors do you get in the `LogCat`?

Comment: i read that changing  LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                 mLocationListeners[0]); to instead be  LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                 mLocationListeners[1]); might work any thoughts

Comment: @JacquesArtgraven Post full error logcat into your question.

Comment: It would be good to see the LogCat stack trace from the crash (you'll see it through ADB for most crashes—if you don't see it, in my experience it tends to be a memory problem) but I notice you haven't checked in case the `Intent` is `null`, which it sometimes is. I doubt that's your problem but feel free to try it.

Comment: hey @AndrewWyld i updated the logCat thanks for the insight, I note forced closing of the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More recent OS versions throw errors when they detect that you're making a bad "user experience" mistake.  Doing network traffic on the UI thread is one of them, which is what your logcat is showing.  You can avoid this by putting that traffic in a separate thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Net traffic here
    }
});
thread.start();
```

You could call your entire `postData()` on that thread like this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
    mLastLocation.set(location);
    String message = String.format(
            "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
            location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());

    Toast.makeText(Bg_process.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    b_c_long = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    b_c_lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        postData();
      }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Hope this helps!